# Add character to end of each row of different lenghts in a block selection

Tags: notepad++

In SSMS and Notepad++, to name a few possibilites, you can edit blocks of text by using ALT+SHIFT, which is great for blocks with rows of the same length. There is an example [here](http://zippy.gfycat.com/WellmadeDefiantAfricanmolesnake.gif), and a discussion on reddit.com/r/sql [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/SQL/comments/39lfaf/i_just_learned_about_altshift_in_ssms/). I was hoping some of you would share how to do the same thing with blocks of text with differing row lengths, like this:

```
 [Adams, John], 
 [Adams, John Quincy], 
 [Arthur, Chester A.], 
 [Buchanan, James], 
 [Bush, George], 
 [Bush, George W.], 
 [Carter, Jimmy], 
 [Coolidge, Calvin], 
 [Cleveland, Grover],
```

To be specific I'm not looking for a script, but  a keyboard shortcut if one exists in any editor you know.

Thanks!

Comment: SQL is a language, it has no keyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use Regex Find & Replace.

1. Select the text, press `Ctrl + H` to open the Find and Replace dialog box.
2. Find what = `$` (this is end-of-line in regex's notation). Replace with = `the character you want`. Look in = `Selection`.
3. Expand Find Options and make sure `Regular Expressions` is checked
4. Hit Replace All

The above instructions are for SSMS. Notepad++ would be similar.